# Matryoshka words

Tags: word-games

Since it's Friday and others are playing games, here's another one to take us into the weekend.

Everyone knows about those Russian nesting dolls (called matryoshka dolls, I believe). A small doll nests inside a larger, which itself is inside a larger doll, and so on.

This game does the same with words. You start with a three-letter word, add a letter to make another word, and so on. Longest word wins. The catch? Each additional letter has to form a legitimate word.

Here's one to start you off:

> bur
>   burr
>   burro
>   burrow
>   burrows

Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're willing to accept the surname "Barrett", the longest I can find (with a program) is **10 letters**, "barretters":

> bar
>    [barr](http://www.wordnik.com/words/barr): to cry as an elephant, abbreviation of "barrister"
>    [barre](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/barre#English): (ballet) A handrail fixed to a wall used for ballet exercises.
>    [barret](http://www.wordnik.com/words/barret): A kind of military cap
>    Barrett: A surname (recall Elizabeth Barrett Browning)
>    [barrette](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/barrette#English): A clasp or clip for gathering and holding the hair.
>    [barretter](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/barretter#English): A ballast resistor
>    [barretters](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/barretters#English): plural form of barretter

Comment: starts off sounding like a beach boys song :)

Comment: We are feeling generous, so I think we'll allow Barrett. And award the check.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find only eight.

> max
>   maxi
>   maxim
>   maxima
>   maximal
>   maximals

Comment: About the "niners": Unfortunately, they all involve obscure words and abbreviations, many of which are hard to accept. Anyway, the list: Romanisms
Romanists
barretter
barrettes
colonials
composers
condoners
contrasts
contrasty
marchesas
marcheses
marineras
marshalls
modernest
tamarinds
tamarisks

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully not breaking the rules here (inserting and prepending allowed):

> I
>   in
>   sin
>   sing
>   sting
>   string
>   staring
>   starling
>   starlings

Comment: Nice try, but that does change the rules. If you allow insertions, that opens it up quite a bit. Interesting twist, though.

Answer (score 1):

I have 7:

- pa
- pas
- past
- paste
- pastel and pastels

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I have:

- Pot
- Pots
- Spots
- Sports
- Sprouts
- Supports

I'm not sure if you're allowed to rearrange letters like I did in *Supports*, so here's another one:

- Pot
- Port
- [Porte](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1279639#m_en_us1279639)
- Porter
- Porters
- [Sporters](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1293393#m_en_us1293393)

Comment: Interesting variation on the game. Opens it up quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

- but
- butt
- [butte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butte)
- butter
- butterfly

Do the rules allow for jumping from butter to butterfly?

Comment: Nice try, but you have to proceed one letter at a time. You could go to *buttery* next, but not *butterfly*.

Answer (score 0):

- cap
- cape
- caper
- capers: the flower buds of the caper plant