# Difference between "abate" and "bate"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences

What is the difference between *abate* and *bate*? How are they used differently? Do they both mean the same thing?

(from the Free Dictionary)

The definition of *abate* is 'to reduce in amount, degree, or intensity; lessen'

The definition of *bate* is 'to lessen the force or intensity of; moderate'

Isn't that the same thing?

I know that *bate* is used in the phrase 'with bated breath'. Is it only commonly used in this phrase and rarely used elsewhere?

What's the difference?

Comment: How nice! I have another "kangaroo word" to add to my collection. :) http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215780/is-there-a-well-known-term-for-the-synonym-or-near-synonym-telescoping-words

Comment: Note "bate" is rare, so avoid it.  Except in "bated breath".  And "bate" used in falconry.  But "abate" is common, so use it.

Answer (score 5):

[***abate***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/abate?searchDictCode=all) is related to [***bate***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bate?searchDictCode=all) etymologically.

> **Bate**
>
> Origin
>
> late Middle English: from Old French **batre** '**to beat**' (see also
>   batter1).
>
> **Abate**
>
> Origin
>
> Middle English (in the legal sense): from Old French abatre 'to fell',
>   from a- (from Latin ad 'to, at') + **batre** '**to beat**' (from Latin
>   battere, battuere 'to beat').

The word picture for *bate* is a hawk beating its wings against the air to fly. This word picture extends metaphorically to its noun definition: "foul mood".

> **Bate**
>
> VERB
>
> Falconry (Of a hawk) beat the wings in agitation and flutter off the
>   perch:
>
> the hawks bated and immediately the breeze got in their feathers
>
> NOUN
>
> British informal (dated) An angry mood:
>
> he got into a stinking bate

"Bate" obtains the meaning of "reducing the intensity of a force" as Shakespeare used it in [Merchant of Venice](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/merchant/full.html). In each of the uses below, *bate* can reflect the meaning "subdue", although in some of them it could also reflect the original word picture of "beat" or "flutter".

> "With *bated* breath and whispering humbleness,"
>
> "His tedious measures with the un*bated* fire"
>
> "These griefs and losses have so *bated* me,"
>
> "And bid the main flood *bate* his usual height;"

By adding the prefix "a" (a phonetic variant of "ad") to the base of *bate* we get the picture of beating **"at"** something or someone.

> **Abate**
>
> VERB
>
> Make (something) less intense:
>
> nothing abated his crusading zeal

Again, *abate* obtains the meaning of "reducing the intensity of a harmful force" from the outcome of beating that harmful force back. In fact, "subdue" is the primary connotation of *abate*.

This is the clear meaning in [Shakespeare's Merchant of Venice](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/merchant/full.html), when BASSANIO says,

> "You would ***abate*** the strength of your displeasure."

So in the end, the common etymology creates common meaning across the board, although *bate* is rarely used now, except for the phrase "bated breath."

Comment: I find this answer confusing and inadequate. You have supplied the meaning (word for word from Oxford Dictionaries) for *bate*; and the etymology (per the same dictionary) for *abate*, with no discussion as to how the two are connected. Whilst it is true that the etymology of both words is given by the dictionary as the same, it puzzles me what the connection is between lessening (abate), and the fluttering of a hawk's wings. Personally I have never used the word *bate* and know nothing much about it. *Abate* is an everyday term.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. This is a work in progress.

Comment: On its face, the batre 'to beat' in both OED Origin lines is sufficient documentation of the claim above it. "Abate is related to bate etymologically."

Comment: OK I accept that they are related etymologically - because the dictionary says so. But I am still mystified as to how they are connected as regards meaning.

Answer (score 0):

There is, of course, the old joke about the cat who ate the cheese and waited for the mouse with "baited" breath.

But back to the actual question...

As I'm sure we all know, a huge fraction of our common English phrases originated in Shakespeare.  Shakespeare was quite happy to twist and modify words for best effect, and alliteration was a favoured tool ("From forth the fatal loins of these two foes" etc.).  So, in the lines quoted above, he chose "bated" as opposed to abated, because it falls better on the ear.  In doing so, I suspect he began the use of the phrase "bated breath".

Given that abated is the older form, and that there is a common tendency to shorten words, it seems obvious to me that bate and bated are simply contractions of abate and abated.  So, I think one could reasonably argue that bated is an example of aphesis and should actually be written as 'bated, in the same way that, "until", becomes 'til.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A person using / recommending 'phone or 'bus (or indeed insisting that Anglophones revert to using Latin) would be one of a tiny minority. Usage determines 'what should be used'.

Answer (score -1):

Scot M gave an exhaustive answer. Here is the simple version: You are correct, they mean basically the same.  However, you also guessed correctly that "bate" is nowadays (at least in America) used almost exclusively in "with bated breath", which means "in intense anticipation" figuratively or literally so excited as to refrain even from breathing. As "bate" is so rare, Americans sometimes misspell this idiom as "with baited breath", an amusing eggcorn (what is it baited with—chocolate? To catch what or whom?)

Comment: Obviously, to bait your breath you eat minnows.

Comment: While I'm very often mocking Americans, I have to "defend" them here, as I'm 100% certain that many people, Americans and non-Americans alike, write "baited" instead of "bated".