# What is the longest dictionary word you can spell where continuing to remove the final letter

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the longest dictionary word you can spell where continuing to remove the final letter will still result in a dictionary word.

e.g. 
ate [dictionary word],
at [last letter 'e' removed still a dictionary word],
a [last letter 't' removed]

No reason for this question, I am just curious.

Comment: Noooooooooooooooo!

Comment: @LordSoth That's not a word.

Comment: Is this Q on topic on ELU?

Comment: A VERY nice puzzle, but not on topic.  But, don't vote to remove it!

Comment: See [Matryoshka words](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16059/matryoshka-words), with quite a few answers that match your question directly, or can be easily extended to match it.

Comment: @RegDwigнt, Edwin Ashworth and Urbycoz. Really? This question is too broad? One answer, and that's proof there are too many possible answers. As for the Matryoshka words, the answers conclude/start with three-letter words and there are only two answers which kinda fit. Ack! No fun on ELU.

Comment: "Anticars" would be an 8-letter example.

Comment: Possibly (or possibly not) on topic in [Puzzling](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) SE

Comment: I may of picked the wrong exchange, Puzzling seems more appropriate. However, with this question been too broad seems incorrect as I'm only after one answer.

Answer (score 2):

My English companion came up with this clever solution when I was looking for the word that covered a horse's saddle, rein and bit during a private lesson

- [**livery**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Livery)  *A distinctive uniform worn by the male servants of a household*.
- [**liver**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/liver) *A large, reddish-brown, glandular vertebrate organ located in the upper right portion of the abdominal cavity that secretes bile*
- [**live**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/live) *To be alive; exist*.
- **[liv](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/liv)** *adj. being four more than fifty*
- [**Li**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/li) *The symbol for the element lithium*, and *a traditional Chinese measure of distance, today standardized at 500 meters*
- **[L](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/L)** *The symbol for the Roman numeral 50.*

Comment: But that's not remove the *last* letter consecutively. The O.P. is looking for that order specifically.

Comment: @Neeku I've changed my answer! :)

Comment: Cool. (: I wonder if there's any other one longer than that. I sent an answer previously which I deleted later as soon as I noticed the O.P. wants the other way around from the end, and you can actually feed a dictionary to a code and make it find that for you. I don't have access to my own PC to try it.

Comment: Man, I hate people who are that good with word puzzles!

Comment: Roman Numerals and Elemental Symbols aren't English words.

Comment: @Oldcat  They're words found in the dictionary, and English is crammed with foreign loan words. The OP asked for a dictionary words, no mention that they had to be Germanic.

Comment: XIV isn't a loan word. It is a number.

Comment: The symbols represent numbers, which are spoken as words. If you disagree, perhaps this would make an interesting question on ELU? Are numbers words? I believe they are, regardless of how they're written be it 54, fifty-four or LIV.

Comment: Cheating a little with the use of elements and roman numerals but a good answer all the same. I might move this question to [Puzzling](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) to see if there any more answers.