# An English word utilized to describe a name or group of word shortened from their full spelling to create a stand alone statement or sentence?

Tags: grammar, abbreviations

I'm looking for a word that describes the shortening of a names full spelling that can by itself be a statement or sentence, thanks for any assistance.

```
        My name.       The shortened sentence
```

Example: Ruben A Rodriguez     =    Rub A Rod

Comment: If you will accept 'abbreviation', your question is off-topic on ELU as too basic. If you will accept 'textspeak', your question is off-topic on ELU as a duplicate.  If you want a more precise term, you should include 'not _abbreviation_ , _textspeak_ etc'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth OP is very specifically looking for a word for an abbreviation of name that is itself a phrase.  A subset of 'Abbreviation' and nothing to do with textspeak.

Comment: @JeffUK Perhaps you are unaware that often answers like 'abbreviation' and 'textspeak' will appear as _answers_ to such a question, and be upvoted. This was a pre-emptive strategem. Although your confidence in what OP is actually looking for, given the lack of clarity in the question ('can be' or 'is'? 'name' or 'group of words'?) seems ill-founded.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth those answers would be incorrect, those upvotes misplaced,  that has no bearing on the meaning of OP's question which is quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no word for such a specific exercise.

Although, in general, what you are engaging in is [**wordplay**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wordplay):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> playful use of words : verbal wit

---

There is no word I could find for "finding one word inside another."

Possible informal terms for such "subwords" include [kangaroo words](https://www.thoughtco.com/kangaroo-word-word-play-1691210) and [matroyshka words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16059/matryoshka-words). But each of those has a specific usage that's quite different from what you're interested in.